# notifying if patient has a fever or not

Tags: java, medical

How would you design an object to send an alert if a patient has a fever, given temperature readings every few minutes? 
Suppose that you have temperature class which will measure class. here is the **class Temperature:**

```
public class Temperature {
    private float temperature;
    private Location location;

    public Temperature(int temperature, Location location) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Temperature(Location location) {
        this.temperature = 0;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public float getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getTemperatureInFahrenheit() {
        return ( temperature * (9/5.0) + 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please? What do you mean by send an alert?

Comment: @NirupIyer by alerting means it would just display a message that patient temperature is getting increased. just like a notifying class.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to print out that temperature has crossed threshold, then add this to your setter

```
public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
    if (temperature > YOUR_THRESHOLD) { System.out.println("BURNING MAN!"); }
}
```

Also, call this setter from your constructor, instead of repeating code.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. but I need something which will give us the result from every minute temperature record

Comment: No where in your code does it show how you are recording the temperature or it's frequency. But however you are doing it, you will probably call the setTemperature() method to update the temperature, hence adding the condition there makes sense. If you have already implemented the recording temperature part, upload that code and we can find another solution,

Answer (score 1):

I would apply an observer pattern, take the look the wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

You will use this pattern when you want to be notified or delivered.

As @Nirup Iyer mention, you should dispatch an event when an alert is activated. You could accept a list of alerts and validate them on set.

Answer (score 0):

I would want to make a dedicated Thread that functions as your fever monitor, and keep the judgement as to whether a temperature is a fever or not one step removed (and under more local control) from the class whose job it is to hold the temperature.

Suppose we had a `JPanel` called FeverMonitor. There are a number of ways to create code that repeats at given time intervals, but a good class for doing this is the `util.Timer`.

You would create a `TimerTask` that checks the Temperature and compares the value to a Fever value. When associating the `TimerTask` to the `Timer`, you have the opportunity to set how much time should elapse between each execution of the task, as well as whether to continually repeat the task or not.

The task could be set to change a value or property of a `JLabel` on FeverMonitor. I'm thinking, for example, every 30 seconds the current temperature of the patient is posted, and if the value is a fever, either the background color or the font color is turned to red.

But a `TimerTask` could also be set to do something like trigger an email or any of a number of tasks that constitute your "notification."

Lastly, the FeverMonitor could even be given the ability to define what constitutes a Fever (100? 102? 104?). The TimerTask can either refer to an instance variable or a new TimerTask can be generated and can replace the previous TimerTask.